Where should the chess pieces be placed in 4x4, 6x6 and 9x9 chessboards?
Here are 3 related chess problems.  The color of the pieces is not important.  Unlike a legal chess game there are no limits to the number of pieces of each type in these puzzles.

Puzzle 1:  On a 4x4 chessboard, place some bishops and some knights (and no other pieces) so that:
Each bishop attacks exactly 3 knights (and nothing else) and
each knight attacks exactly 1 bishop (and nothing else).

Puzzle 2:  On a 6x6 chessboard, place some knights and some rooks (and no other pieces) so that:
Each knight attacks exactly 4 rooks (and nothing else) and
each rook attacks exactly 1 knight (and nothing else).

Puzzle 3:  On a 9x9 chessboard, place some bishops and some kings (and no other pieces) so that:
Each bishop attacks exactly 3 kings (and nothing else) and
each king attacks exactly 2 bishops (and nothing else).

Attribution:  Erich Friedman

Solutions to all 3:

 

You can actually use the requirements to create ratios that help solve the puzzle:

For instance, in the first, each bishop attacks exactly 3 knights, whereas each knight attacks 1 bishop, so the ratio of knights to bishops will be 3:1. This means the solution will be a multiple of this.

Furthermore for the knight puzzles; due to the way the knights attack, if it is attacking a bishop or a rook it won't be under attack from that same rook or bishop. This means in both puzzles 1 and 2, there has to be at least 2x the ratio to solve - and in both cases the solution is exactly 2x.


@Lucenaposition fixed

+1 Your doubling argument about the knights is clever.

Your logic does not apply in general. On larger grids, we can find solutions with different ratios.

Indeed (re:@DanielMathias), it appears you can remove one or two of the "inner" kings from the solution to puzzle 3 and break the ratio?  And in puzzle 1, on a larger board, you could add additional knights attacking the bishops while not being attacked themselves?
